# Discord.py bot is unable to do something yet another bot with same code can

Tags: discord, discord.py

So my bot able to go through channels and clear specific messages, but now it can't do it because of missing access. I made an another bot and fired up the same code. And it worked. How is this possible? I don't think there is a problem with the code, but with the bot itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your bot has permissions set in discord.com/developers/applications - Under the bot tab make sure you've checked all the appropriate boxes. If you are truly running identical code that is most likely your issue.

Comment: it has all necessary permissions

Comment: Is it possible that someone removed roles/access from your original bot? Seems strange that identical code would be working differently.

Comment: nothing have changed